# how to get data from access to excel in html format using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

The database in Access is from an ODBC database. The data i need is in a memo field has around 10,000 characters. I usually copy + paste in excel using HTML format.

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
```

However, i want to automate this process and i have tried to incorporate it into the following code. The PasteSpecial does not work after making the connection.

```
Private Sub RetrieveRecordset(strSQL As String, clTrgt As Range)
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: To retrieve a recordset from a database (via an SQL query)  and place
 '               it in the supplied worksheet range
 'NOTE         : Requires a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library"
 '               (Developed with reference to version 2.0 of the above)
Dim cnt1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rcArray As Variant
Dim lFields As Long
Dim lRecrds As Long 
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
'Open connection to the database
cnt1.Open glob_sConnect
'Open recordset based on Orders table
rst1.Open strSQL, cnt1
'Count the number of fields to place in the worksheet
lFields = rst1.Fields.Count
'Copy the recordset from the database
On Error Resume Next
clTrgt.CopyFromRecordset rst1  
'CopyFromRecordset will fail if the recordset contains an OLE
'object field or array data such as hierarchical recordsets
If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo EarlyExit
EarlyExit:
'Close and release the ADO objects
rst1.Close
cnt1.Close
Set rst1 = Nothing
Set cnt1 = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub GetRecords()
'Find the newest record which contains data which has previously been used for each database

'Generate the SQL queries
sFCESQLQry = " SELECT...."

'Paste in Workbook

wbFurnace.Activate
Set rngTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Range("A1").PasteSpecial **Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True**
Call RetrieveRecordset(sFCESQLQry, rngTarget)

End Sub
```

The PasteSpecial does not work in this case. It does work it if I use x1Pasteall but the data is in tabular rather than HTML format i want. Any ideas on the problem?
Let me know if there are alternate methods to get the data in html format.

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no method to integrate and output HTML on
 an Access report. If plain text is acceptable then you could load the HTML
 string into the Web Browser control on say a hidden form, grab the Text only
 prop of the HTML document object within the control, and copy that back to
 an unbound TextBox control on your report. You would do this in the Format
 event of the relevant section.     Pl refer                                                                   <http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/dealing-with-html-code-in-a-memo-field.2168966/>

Comment: thanks! ill try it out.